# Is it possible in Robot Framework to have a list of the tests it will run?

Tags: robotframework

Since Robot Framework can accept folders to be run as argument and it is possible to apply some filters on the tests to run (e.g. based on the tag), I'd like to know if there is a way to list the tests it will run before their execution. Reading the documentation I couldn't find such option.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the section [Programatic modification of test data](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-modification-of-test-data), the user guide describes the [visitor interface](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.model.html#module-robot.model.visitor) which can be used to examine the working set before the first test is run, and to apply filters of your choosing. You can also use this same mechanism to simply list out the suites and tests that will be run.

If all you need is some very basic filtering, you can add tags to your individual tests, or tests in suite, and then choose to run only tests with or without those tags via command line arguments. For example, we use tags for "production-safe", "in-progress", "smoke", and a few others which lets us run subsets of tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--include` for tags or `--test` `--suite` for tests/suites.
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-command-line-options